# Including an @ in a c# configuration file

Tags: c#, sql, configuration

I have some SQL queries in a configuration file. They are parameterized so have an @ in them. They will only be valid XML if they have that replaced with `&amp;` instead of @ but this will break the SQL. Is there an elegant way to avoid having to decode the string myself?

Comment: Your XML parser will decode the string for you.  (Assuming that you encode it correctly, which you aren't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They will only be valid XML if they have that replaced with `&amp;` instead of @

Nope. That is `&`, `@` is fine.

In any case, the XML parser will decode `&amp;` into `&` when it reads the string. You should never have to do it manually.